# Always getting TypeError: $(...). is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I work in asp.net mvc and I want to make jquery plugin.
I try to find solution on forums ,but always getting same error.
I wrote something like:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        fillcombo: function(options) {
            var datadef = {
                                region:"",
                                num:"",
                                filter1:"",
                                filter2:""
            };

            options = $.extend(datadef, options);
            $.ajax({
                url:        "Main/SyncCombo",
                dataType:   "json",
                type:       "GET",
                data:     datadef ,            
                success: function (response) {

                    this.empty();
                    var optionhtml1 = '<option value="' + 0 + '"></option>';
                    this.append(optionhtml1);
                    $.each(response, function (i) {
                        var optionhtml = '<option value="' + response[i].CODE.toString() + '">' + response[i].DESCR + '</option>';
                        this.append(optionhtml);
                    });
                 }
             });

        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Later i want to call it with:

```
$('#cbBox').fillcombo({ region: region, num: num, filter1: filter1, filter2: filter2 });
```

Where region, num etc are variables that i need to pass to ajax...
But firebug i always get error

```
TypeError: $(...).fillcombo is not a function


...x').fillcombo({ region: region, num: num, filter1: filter1, filter2: filter2 })
```

I will add that I am not sure how to define data in ajax when I write plugin, i try this way,and like region, num , etc i get same error...
This is first time to me to write jquery plugin and I don't have a clue where i make mistake. 
Please help..
Tnx

Comment: you have added required js files on your page???

Comment: Yes , I am. Some other fn in this file work on call , but they are not plugins...

Comment: Try assigning it directly instead of `extend`. like this: `$.fn.fillcombo =`.

Comment: is working functions using jQuery instance ($) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution, i just clear cache from mozzila, after that i get second error for `this.empty()` then i define `var self = this;` and use self not this...